# what is the matching datatype in Faker library for 'xmltype'?

Tags: python, faker, test-data

I am trying to create dummy data for my tables using Faker Library. I have column with datatype as 'xmltype'. Which option I should select in Faker library for xmltype?
or pl give any other suggestions for creating dummy data for xmltype

Comment: Could you add an example of the input you are trying to generalize using faker?

Comment: I want to fill my table with random data as per the datatype of the columns

If my table schema is {col1: int, col2: string, col3:boolean}. I want few records with random data but with matching datatype like below

col1   col2   col3
99     xxx     false